# Asociar cada fila a elementos separados por barra diagonal

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Dispongo de la siguiente hoja de cálculo de Google, donde algunos textos podrían estar separados por barra diagonal (‘/’):

[image: base de datos]

He adaptado el script para que separe y escriba en otra hoja cada uno de los códigos de la primera columna en varias filas, tantas como códigos haya en cada celda, manteniendo los textos del resto de las columnas.  Este seria el resultado:

[image: Resultado mi script]

Hasta ahí, todo ok. Ahora necesito que haga lo mismo, pero que considere también los textos separados de las segunda y tercera columna mediante barras diagonales y le asigne a cada fila, en el mismo orden que están escritas inicialmente, cada uno de los elementos.
Por ejemplo, si la primera columna tenemos 111/555/5545 y en la segunda A/B/C, el código debe asignar a 111 el valor A, a 555 el valor B y a 5545 el valor C.
Del mismo modo, asignarían para cada elemento de la segunda fila (112/2521/2541/555) los valores G, H, T y U, respectivamente.
Los valores de la segunda columna y la tercera tendrán siempre 1 elemento o bien tantos como haya en la primera.
El resultado del nuevo código seria este:

[image: Nuevo código]

Aquí mi código:

```
function formatTest() {
// File
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get rawData sheet
var rawData = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
// Input data
var data = rawData.getRange("A1:C").getValues(); // Gets titles and options in a single call to the 
sheet
// Initialise an array that will hold the output
var outputArray = [];
// Name a variable to hold the data from each set of options
var options; 

// Start looping through the data
for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
// Split the options into an array: "Option1, Option2, Option3" ---> [Option1, Option2, Option3]
//options = data[row][0].split(","); // sin convertir datos en string
options = data[row][0].toString().split("/"); 
// Loop through the array of split options and place each of them in a new row
for (var element = 0; element < options.length; element++) {                
//outputArray.push([options[element], data[row][1],data[row][2]]);  // options[element]=>>  Place the 
title in a new row // resto =>> Place one option in the 2nd column of the row
    outputArray.push([options[element], data[row][1],data[row][2]]);             

} // Options loop ends here

} // Data loop ends here
// Get processedData sheet
var processedData = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
// clear existing
processedData.clear()
// Get last row in processedData sheet
var lastRow = processedData.getLastRow();


// Post the outputArray to the sheet in a single call
processedData.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, outputArray.length, 
outputArray[0].length).setValues(outputArray);
}
```

Comment: El código lo adapté gracias a este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549459/how-to-transpose-and-split-in-google-apps-script. Pero no consigo que haga lo que pido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He estado trabajando con lo que consulté. Ahí va mi código de principiante. Por su puesto, siempre será mejorable por los expertos de esta maravillosa página. Si alguien ve algún error o instrucción sobrante o faltante, que comente. De momento, he comprobado que funciona y hace lo que pido. Con permiso, lo dejo como aporte, por si a alguien le interesa.

```
function myFunctionUno() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("idSheet"); // Archivo con su ID // Cambiar por la ID
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Hoja 4"); // Hoja Input
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 5'); // Hoja Output

sheet2.clear(); // Limpia valores Hoja 2

var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues(); // Obtiene valores de la hoja 1 (array) 
para si ejecución

var num = 0;
var str; var res;
var str2; var res2;
var str3; var res3;
var outputArray = [];

// INICIO BUCLE CON EL DATA (HOJA 1)
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

// Columna 1 principal
str = data[i][0];
res = str.split("/");

// COLUMNA ESTADOS (1 VALOR O > 1 VALOR)
str2 = data[i][1];
res2 = str2.split("/");

// COLUMNA PRUEBA (1 VALOR O > 1 VALOR)
str3 = data[i][2];
res3 = str3.split("/");

 // 2DO BUCLE DEL ARRAY Y COLOCA ELEMENTOS EN NUEVAS FILAS SEGÚN CONDICIONES
 for (var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
 num++;

 if ((res2.length == 1) && (res3.length == 1)){
 outputArray.push([res[j],data[i][1],data[i][2]]); 
 }
 else if ((res2.length == 1) && (res3.length > 1)){
 outputArray.push([res[j],data[i][1],res3[j]]); 
 }
 else if ((res2.length > 1) && (res3.length == 1)){
 outputArray.push([res[j],res2[j],data[i][2]]); 
 }
 else if ((res2.length > 1) && (res3.length > 1)){
 outputArray.push([res[j],res2[j],res3[j]]); 
 }

 }
 }
 sheet2.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).setBackground('#00ffff'); // colorea encabezado

 sheet2.getRange(1, 1, outputArray.length, 
 outputArray[0].length).setValues(outputArray);
 }
 // NOTAS : POSIBILIDADES COLUMNAS 2 Y 3 SEGÚN DELIMITACIONES POR '/'
 // SI res2.length = 1 Y res3.length = 1 *
 // SI res2.length = 1 y res3.length > 1 *
 // SI res2.length > 1 y res3.length = 1 *
 // SI res2.length > 1 y res3.length > 1 *
```